# Extending several lines at once using polygon reference layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, polyline-creation, extend

I have transverse shapefile lines (blue line) with a fixed length and I would like to extend them (orange line) using another reference layer (green polygon) that has a variable shape.

The 'extend' command built into QGIS 3.22 does this function, however it stretches the line with uniform sizes, however in my case each cross line will have a different size according to the reference layer (green polygon).

[image]

In QGIS 3.22 (or other versions) is there something that solves this problem?

Update: i add my files problem

https://github.com/wesleysc352/wesleysc352.github.io/blob/master/files.zip

Comment: the blue line layer is a real line layer or points styled as lines?

Comment: Hi Bernd Logge, blue line is real shapefile

Answer (score 5):

You could use the said extend lines function, use a huge number for extending the lines to ensure they are all completely within the polygon and then clip the too long lines to the polygon. That's just two processing steps.

In case you end up with lines having two or more parts in the polygon you can run multiparts to singleparts on the lines and delete the parts that disjoin the small red line from your screenshot, e.g. by using extract by location, extracting the parts that intersect with the red line.

Comment: Hello MrXsquared, I did this using the reference layer (green polygon) to cut the extended lines. However, as my reference layer is very sinuous, some lines ended up crossing the reference layer twice, which I didn't like.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Could be done with two additional steps, see update.

Comment: Your idea is very interesting, now I understand, however these steps would require me to delete them manually, something very laborious, but it is an alternative for simple situations

Comment: additionally would it be possible to filter the singleparts based on the position of the original transverse lines?

Comment: No, you dont need to do it manually. Just use extract by location and get those line parts intersecting with the red line.

Answer (score 5):

Some small python script you can use:

1. Access the layers
2. Set a threshold (your source layers need to be in the same unit). The value needs to be big enough.
3. Extend lines using `native:extendlines`
4. Clip the overlapping using `native:clip`
5. Add the layer to the map
6. Filter all multipart segments which may intersect a second time with the polygon

```py
from qgis import processing

# Load layers
blue_lines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("blue_lines")[0]
green_polygon = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("green_polygon")[0]

# Set distance value
distance = 5000

# Extend Lines 
temp_layer1 = processing.run("native:extendlines", {
    'INPUT' : blue_lines, 
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
    'START_DISTANCE' : distance,
    'END_DISTANCE' : distance
})['OUTPUT']

# Clip
resultLayer = processing.run("native:clip", {
    'INPUT' : temp_layer1, 
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
    'OVERLAY' : green_polygon
})['OUTPUT']

# Iterate over all features and remove multiparts
resultLayer.startEditing()
for feature in resultLayer.getFeatures():
    
    # Create a multi_polyline from the geometry of each feature
    multi_polyline = feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()
    
    # Iterate over each multi polyline segment so we can find the correct ones
    for polyline in multi_polyline:
        
        # Create a temorary geometry
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x) for x in polyline])
        
        # Iterate over all blue line features 
        for blue_lines_feature in blue_lines.getFeatures():
            
            # Create a small buffer around the segment 
            # and see if any of the blue line geometries is totaly within
            if blue_lines_feature.geometry().within(geom.buffer(1,5)):
                
                # If it is within update the geometry
                resultLayer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({feature.id(): geom}) 
                
                
resultLayer.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resultLayer)
```

**Update:**
If your polygon has sharp turns it's better to identify the correct multipart element by creating a small buffer around the extended lines so we can check which blue lines are 100% within those buffers. Those segments are kept within the result layer.

[image]

Comment: Nice all-in-one solution, though you will need to add the intersect operation that @MrXsquared mentions in the last line  of their answer, else there will be 'floating' clipped lines in the situation described in wesleysc352's first comment on that answer. As an aside, your `numpy` import is not needed in this case :)

Comment: Updated my answer. The problem with the solution of @MrXsquared would be that it could be that the middle line would also intersect the extended lines. So extract by location wouldn't work all the time. Therefore iterating over the MultiPolyline and only keeping the first element is the most sufficient way.

Comment: @Matt Nice, though. :D

Comment: Updated once more as the reversing didn't work that well. using a small buffer and checking which initial blue lines are 100% within the buffer is a better solution

Comment: Hi Bernad, how can i apply this code in my situation i have no experience with coding in qgis.  is there any console inside the gis?

Comment: Plugins --> Python Console (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html) -> Show Editor -> Paste the code -> Change the names to your layers in the first lines of code -> Run Script -> Will create a temporary layer, if you need the data persistent save the layer as shp, geojson etc.

Comment: I tested your solution, however the extended lines exceeded the "greenpolygon". Also, the shell gives me a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax error message
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resultLayer)
<QgsVectorLayer: 'Clipped' (memory)>`

Comment: Don't know why you see this SyntaxError message. ```<QgsVectorLayer: 'Clipped' (memory)>``` should be the correct output. Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using qgis 3.22.5, but I also have versions 2.18 and 3.16, I'm going to test them